# Using multiple versions of the Windows Platform SDK with VS 2008 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, platform-sdk

How do I use multiple multiple versions of the Windows Platform SDK for VC++ native code development with VS 2008 Professional : like [The Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en) and the one installed by default here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the "Windows SDK Configuration Tool" which gets installed with any SDK.
When you start that tool, it shows you all the installed SDK's to choose from, and the one you choose is then used in VS2008.